# Using linq group by to show data in a datagridview in a windows form application

Tags: linq, group-by

I am trying to use the LINQ group by function to show data from a database table in a datagridview in a windows form application.  All I can figure out is how to print it to the console, if a listview would be better I am open to that, but I don't know how to do that either.  I am very new to LINQ.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext

        Dim groupQuery = From x In db.Peoples
                         Group By x.State Into Group
                     
        For Each Group In groupQuery

           Console.WriteLine("State {0}", Group.State)

            For Each person In Group.Group
               Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person.First_Name, person.Last_Name)
           Next

       Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = groupQuery
   
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How would I put the data in a datagridview?

Comment: DataGridView doesn’t, in itself, support nested/parent-child views.  The older DataGrid does. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a63a483-5b15-40d6-afb4-8add6b4f244f/nested-datagrid-views?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8